# How to write string to file specified by a user in Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save text received after OCR to a file. This is the function that I use to write everything that there is in EditText 'Wynik' to a file "test.txt". I cannot find any solution to save received text to a file specified by app user f.e. 'My book.txt'

```
 private void SaveText() {
        String TekstDoOdczytu = Wynik.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;


        try{
            
            fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(TekstDoOdczytu.getBytes());
            Wynik.getText().clear();    //Czyszczenie edittexta z tesktu
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text written to file test.txt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Exception", "Error: File write failed: " + e.toString());
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()`. [This sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor) (and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor)) demonstrate the use of `CreateDocument()`. They are covered in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-004.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: `fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", MODE_APPEND);` You only have to change that to `fos = openFileOutput("My bookt.txt", MODE_APPEND);`